# onAccessibilityEvent not triggers on Huawei for app deletion dialog?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, huawei-mobile-services

The app has admin access already and is added in protected apps.

I have an calls extending the AccessibilityService where I what to prevent the user from deleting the app.

The onServiceConnected is called and I set serviceInfo config to:

```
    AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
    config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;
```

The manifest XMl has the service added:

```
<service
        android:name=".myapp.service.myService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
    </service>
```

The onAccessibilityEvent is not called when the user long presses on the app icon and drags it to the trash and confirmation dialog is presented on the screen.

In the onAccessibilityEvent I try to close this dialog programmatically so the user can not delete the app.

Comment: Any luck to this solution? Its also happening in OPPO phones.

Comment: Unfortunately not